# Copy Multiple Files in a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, asynchronous, copy

I've the following scenario, I've to copy multiple (about 10,50,200,...) files. I do that syncronously one after another. This is my code snippet for that.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"";
            FileSystemWatcher listener = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
            listener.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(listener_Created);
            listener.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit") ;
        }

        public static void listener_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            while (!IsFileReady(e.FullPath)) ;
            File.Copy(e.FullPath, @"D:\levani\FolderListenerTest\CopiedFilesFolder\" + e.Name);
        }
```

So when files are created in some folder and it's ready to use I copy that file one after another, but I need to start copying as soon as any file is ready to use. So I think I should use Threads. So.. **How to implement parallel copying?**

@Chris

**Check if file is ready**

```
public static bool IsFileReady(String sFilename)
        {
            // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
            // is no longer locked by another process.
            try
            {
                using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(sFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    if (inputStream.Length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Also a word of warning...I believe that the created event fires when the file is first created. If the file is taking some time to create you may find that you are trying to process it before it has finished being written...

Comment: @Chris look here while (!IsFileReady(e.FullPath)) ;

Comment: D'oh! :) How are you checking that out of interest? I never found any particularly nice ways of checking it...

Comment: nice, cheers. Feels a little clunky but looks effective so shouldn't complain. I guess I keep hoping for an event that tells you when a file is closed or something. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing parallel I/O from a mechanical disk is a bad idea and will only slow things down, as the mechanical head needs to spin every time to seek the next read location (a very slow process) and will then be bounced around as each thread gets its turn to run.

Stick to the sequential approach and read the files in a single thread.

Answer (score 2):

Now only that (what @Tudor says), but copying files in parallel will create mess out of your hard drive, due to fragmenting.  In my app, I use queued copying of 200 simultaneously previously generated files, just to put them on the hard drive in 'linear' fashion.

You can read some more on the subject [here](http://www.videophill.com/blog/how-to-reduce-hard-drive-fragmentation/).

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly have one `Thread` which does all the processing i.e.

```
Queue files = new Queue();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
      string path = @"";
      FileSystemWatcher listener = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
      Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessFiles));
      t.Start();
      listener.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(listener_Created);
      listener.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

      while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit") ;
}


public static void listener_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    files.Enqueue(e.FullPath);
}

void ProcessFiles()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(files.Count > 0)
        {
              String file = files.Dequeue();
              while (!IsFileReady(file)) ;

              File.Copy(file, @"D:\levani\FolderListenerTest\CopiedFilesFolder\" +           file);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your `listener` event add the file name to a queue.

Then in your `Thread` you can grab the file name from the queue and do your processing from there.

Comment: and still that will be single threaded synchronous work, won't it?

Comment: Yes it would as all processing will be on one `Thread`.  However, you can still do processing after the `Thread` has started leaving you to get on with other processing in `Main`.

Comment: Thanks approach, that looks handsome